# Executing an outer query with multiple sub-queries using OR operator in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I'm trying to run an outer query with multiple sub-queries using `OR` operator in Oracle.

```
select trim(upper(countryname))countryname from countries where countryid in 
          (
          select countryid from partnerbranches where trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193) or
          select countryid from branches where trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193)
          );
```

After running statement above, this error appears, 
`ORA-00936: missing expression`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use with clause:

```
 With countries_ as(
      select countryid from partnerbranches where trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193) 
 Union all
      select countryid from branches where trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193)
      )
 select trim(upper(countryname))countryname from countries c,  countries_ where c.countryid = countries_.countryid
```

Answer (score 1):

The `or` should be `union` as you are combining two sets (or `union all`, since an `in` expression is already implicitly distinct).

Your non-working query is equivalent to this simplified example:

```
select * from dual d1where d1.dummy in
       (
         select d2.dummy from dual d2
         or  -- << This is the problem
         select d3.dummy from dual d3
       );
```

Replace the `or` with `union all`:

```
select trim(upper(countryname)) countryname
from   countries
where  countryid in
       ( select countryid
         from   partnerbranches
         where  trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193)
         union all
         select countryid
         from   branches
         where  trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193)
       );
```

You can avoid repeating the branchcode query by nesting the `union` and applying the branch filter to the result:

```
select trim(upper(countryname)) countryname
from   countries
where  countryid in
       ( select countryid from
         ( select countryid, branchcode from partnerbranches
           union
           select countryid, branchcode from branches )
         where  trim(upper(branchcode)) in
                ( select trim(upper(pbranchcode))
                  from   remittances
                  where  remittanceid = 76193 )
       )
```

or by defining it as a CTE/'WITH' clause:

```
with branchcodes (branch) as
     ( select trim(upper(pbranchcode)) from remittances where remittanceid = 76193 )
select trim(upper(countryname)) countryname
from   countries
where  countryid in
       ( select countryid
         from   partnerbranches
         where  trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select branch from branchcodes)
         union all
         select countryid
         from   branches
         where  trim(upper(branchcode)) in (select branch from branchcodes)
       );
```

or some combination of the two.

It might even be neater as a join:

```
select trim(upper(countryname)) as countryname
from   remittances r
       join ( select countryid, branchcode from partnerbranches
              union
              select countryid, branchcode from branches ) br
            on  trim(upper(br.branchcode)) = trim(upper(r.pbranchcode)) 
       join countries c
            on  c.countryid = br.countryid
where  r.remittanceid = 76193
```

or perhaps more simply:

```
select trim(upper(c.countryname)) as countryname
from   remittances r
       left join partnerbranches pb
            on  trim(upper(pb.branchcode)) = trim(upper(r.pbranchcode)) 
       left join branches br
            on  trim(upper(br.branchcode)) = trim(upper(r.pbranchcode)) 
       join countries c
            on  c.countryid in (pb.countryid, br.countryid)
where  r.remittanceid = 76193
```

Just to add, if you do want to use `in` or `or` with subqueries, each subquery needs its own set of brackets, for example:

```
select * from dual d1 where d1.dummy in
       ( (select d2.dummy from dual d2), (select d3.dummy from dual d3) )
```

or

```
select * from dual d1
where  d1.dummy = (select d2.dummy from dual d2)
or     d1.dummy = (select d3.dummy from dual d3)
```